# Ajax call inside ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button on my webpage. If a user clicks it, a task starts and returns a ID. I want to use this ID to check the progress of the task in another ajax call, to let the user know if the task was completed.

I have tried this, but I don't think it is the correct way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#get-user-transactions').click(function() {

        $( "#user-transactions" ).after( "<p>Loading data</p>" );

            $.ajax({
                url: "/start-task/",
                dataType: "json", 
                success: function(data){ 
                    if(data) { 

                        var stateCheck = setInterval(   

                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/check-taskstate/"+data.task_id,
                                dataType: "json", 
                                success: function(data){ 

                                   if (data.updated == 'true') {
                                       clearInterval(stateCheck);
                                       window.location.reload();
                                   }
                                } 

                            })//ajax

                        , 1000); //stateCheck   


                    }                        

                } 

            })//ajax

    });
});
</script>
```

## Edit

I updated my code, so the first url also gives a json response. But If I try my code I get this error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: for what do you use setinterval?

Comment: doesnt this code work? where is the problem?

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef I need to do a check every second to the `/check-taskstate/<ID>` to see if the task is completed

Comment: This seems a code review task, as the OP is not handling any error

Comment: Why do you need two AJAX calls? Can't you do everything on the server at once?

Comment: @DavidJones: No, Im starting a celery-task with my first view: http://www.celeryproject.org

Comment: I think Im closer to getting it to work, but now I get an error. Question is updated.

Comment: It might be the whole issue of putting the raw `$.ajax` in setInterval.  Wrap that in an anonymous function and see what happens.

Comment: @MichaelChaney: Could you give some example code of your suggestion?

Comment: Hope it will help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052741/dynamic-select-options-php-and-mysql/27052831#27052831)

Comment: Call the inner ajax in another function and then call that function here.

Comment: The answer below is exactly what I was suggesting and should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) accepts a function or code but you are passing an [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object you must be getting error for that.

> func is the function you want to be called repeatedly
>
> code in the alternate syntax, is a string of code you want to be executed repeatedly (using this syntax is not recommended for the same reasons as using eval())

Use

```
var stateCheck = setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/check-taskstate/"+data.task_id,
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function(data){ 

           if (data.updated == 'true') {
               clearInterval(stateCheck);
               window.location.reload();
           }
        } 

    });
}, 1000); //stateCheck
```