# Javascript modal confirm box values to store in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, modal-dialog

I have a webpage consisting of games. Now before the page loads, I have a modal dialog box which comes up and asks users about their dominant hand, i.e., if they are left handed or right handed. Here is the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/uvj3ktan/ .

HTML code

```
<div id="boxes">
  <div id="dialog" class="window">
  What is your dominant hand?
     <div id="popupfoot"> <a href="#" class="close agree">Left Hand</a> | <a class="agree"style="color:red;" href="#">Right Hand</a> </div>
  </div>
<div id="mask"></div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Javascript/jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

var id = '#dialog';

//Get the screen height and width
var maskHeight = $(document).height();
var maskWidth = $(window).width();

//Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
$('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

//transition effect
$('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
$('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9);  

//Get the window height and width
var winH = $(window).height();
var winW = $(window).width();

//Set the popup window to center
$(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
$(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

//transition effect
$(id).fadeIn(2000);     

//if close button is clicked
$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
//Cancel the link behavior
e.preventDefault();

$('#mask').hide();
$('.window').hide();
});

//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
$(this).hide();
$('.window').hide();
});

});
```

What I am planning to do is, when the user clicks on either of the option, that particular option should get stored in the database against that user. As of now, its redirecting to the same page. I have a user database ready. I somehow need to store their dominant hand values into the database.

The webpage is .tpl(php) and the pop up is jquery/javascript. I am using mysql as my database.

Comment: get a hand value and pass that variable with $.ajax to php file then insert into your database .. its very simple

Comment: Hi Mohamed, could you please elaborate/jsfiddle.. I am not able to understand it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052741/dynamic-select-options-php-and-mysql/27052831#27052831    .. this to how to pass variables  between js and php